# Given a pile of items, split them into meaningful groups by comparing them

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, categorization

Given that I have a 'pile' of items that need to be split in groups, and given that I can express how much these items differ, relative to eachother, in a number, a score if you will, how would I separate this input into meaningful groups?

I recognise that this is a bit of an abstract question, so to try and make it clearer here is what I have tried so far:

I have tried representing the input as a weighted graph in which every vertex is connected to every other vertex, with the 'strength' of the edge being their relative score. Then I'd take the longest edge of the graph, and separate every other vertex by 'closeness' to the vertices at the end of that longest edge. This works reasonably well, but has the disadvantage of always yielding two groups for a result, which might not necessarily be logical.

For example: say I can express the differentness of fruits in a number. Then given a pile of apples, the different brand of apples would form different categories, like Elstar, Jonagold, what have you... But when I'd have a pile consisting of apples, pears, and oranges, then the apples would be relatively similar and should fall into the same category.

I'm guessing I'd have to remove every edge of the graph bigger than the mean plus the standard deviation or something like that, and then see how many disjointed subgraphs appear, but I'd like to hear the approach of someone with more mathematical knowledge than me.

Comment: There may be something useful [looking at cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

What you are referring to is clustering.  You seem to have a "distance" matrix between two items, although this is probably some inverse of the "strength" metric.  A distance metric is non-negative and 0 when two things are equal.  The larger the value the further apart the items.

When you have a generic "distance" matrix, a typical clustering method is hierarchical/agglomerative clustering ("distance" is in quotes because it might not meet all the formal qualities of a distance).  A good place to start in understanding this technique is the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering).  The ideas behind hierarchical clustering can be applied to non-fully connected graphs.

I would expect almost every statistics package to include some form of hierarchical clusters.